# Bootstrap: Logo not centering on landing page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full screen background image for my website landing page with my logo in the centre. The website uses Bootstrap and is fully responsive. The logo is vertically and horizontally aligned in my browser window and when the window is resized the logo correctly stays in the centre. But when viewing on a phone or tablet the image background images resizes correctly but the logo does not stay in the centre of the page, but is situated to the right of the screen with half of it obscured.

Any ideas on how I might rectify this? The website landing page is live you can find it at www.burnser.com

Here's the code:

```
<img alt="full screen background image" src="img/bg.jpg" id="full-screen-   
background-image" /> 
<div class="centered">
<a href="work.html"><img src="img/home_logo.png" alt="BB Logo" width="200"   
height="137"></a>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS I'm using:

```
#full-screen-background-image {
z-index: -999;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.centered {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
/* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine on my phone. Try another browser and also try to prefix `transform`.

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Btw, 1MB background image is huge. You should blur that noise out to reduce size of image.

Comment: Thanks DesVal! That's good to know it works on your phone. Will do some more testing and try out the prefixes.

Great tip on the background image by the way. Didn't realise that much noise adds so much weight to file size. But makes sense when you think about it. Got it down to 176kb. Great stuff!